# How can I remove last line and user name from my DDL query using regex?

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

*I am using 11GR2*

I am trying to see the definition of my trigger but when check my result, I see extra line at end of my trigger ALTER TRIGGER "USER"."EMP" ENABLE ....I dont want to see this line as well as "USER".   How can I delete them from my DDL result using regex?

***My Query to see definition of trigger without user name:***

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE ( REPLACE ( dbms_metadata.get_ddl ('TRIGGER', 'TRIGGER_NAME'), '""USER"".'),'^\s+', NULL, 1, 0, 'm') FROM dual
```

***Result:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "USER"."EMP"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    of salary
    on employee
    for each row
   declare
       v_error VARCHAR2(20);
    begin
       if :new.salary > 10
      then
           v_error:=:old.first_name||' cannot have that much!';
           raise_application_error(-20999,v_error);
       end if;
end;
ALTER TRIGGER "USER"."EMP" ENABLE
```

***Expected Result:***

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "EMP"
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
    of salary
    on employee
    for each row
   declare
       v_error VARCHAR2(20);
    begin
       if :new.salary > 10
      then
           v_error:=:old.first_name||' cannot have that much!';
           raise_application_error(-20999,v_error);
       end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TRIGGER','EMP'), 
                     '(CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER )("[A-Z]+"\.)(.+)(ALTER TRIGGER .+)', 
                     '\1\3', 1, 0, 'n')
FROM dual;
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85835/29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did edit my Query. Can you please modify your result. Thanks!